# Are there URL specific hashCode methods?

Tags: java, algorithm, url, caching, hashcode

Is there a way for a memory efficient "ID generation" of an URL?

At the moment I have a cache ala `Set<String>` for my URLs and I can easily check if the URL was already resolved by my crawler or not. Now this requires a lot of memory and I replaced it with `Set<Long>` and used the hashCode of the URLs. The problem now is that even for 40k URLs there are 10 conflicts. An improved method which uses long instead of the `int hashCode` improves it a bit to 6 conflicts, but especially short urls look very similar at the beginning made problems:

5852015146777169869 http://twitpic.com/5xuwuk vs. http://twitpic.com/5xuw7m 5852015146777169869

So I ended up in the following URL-specific double hashing method which gives no conflicts for 2.5mio URLs which is fine for me:

```
public static long urlHashing(String str) {
    if (str.length() < 2)
        return str.hashCode();

    long val = longHashCode(str, 31, false);
    if (str.length() > 3)
        // use the end of the string because those short URLs
        // are often identical at the beginning
        return 43 * val + longHashCode(str.substring(str.length() / 2), 37, true);
    return val;
}

public static long longHashCode(String str, int num, boolean up) {
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0)
        return 0;

    long h = 0;
    // copying to a temp arry is a only a tiny bit slower in our case.
    // so this here is ~2ms faster for 40k urls
    if (up)
        for (int i = 0; i < len;) {
            h = num * h + str.charAt(i++);
        }
    else
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0;) {
            h = num * h + str.charAt(i--);
        }

    return h;
}
```

BUT Now I wondered: are there some theories or (google ;)) papers about URL specific hashing algorithms? Or simply: can I further reduce the conflicts for URLs or do you see any problems or improvements for my current solution?

Update:

- Another approach is to separate the URL by protocol, address and file like it is done in the `new URL(str).hashCode()` method (which cannot be directly used as it is very slow -> it resolves the URL on the fly :/)
- See [squid-cache.org](http://squid-cache.org) or the [CacheDigest explanation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/CacheDigests)

Comment: This seems like a ripe place for a bloom filter, or a bloom filter backed `Set`

Comment: ah, yes. bloom filter, I temporarly forgot those. thanks, I'll check! :)

Comment: @Elliot would you mind creating an answer out of it ... to give you kudos!

Comment: One disadvantage of the bloomfilter is that I cannot partially reset it. When using the `Set<Long>` approach I can easily implement a caching behaviour (throwing out older entries) and also it was slower when using a bloomfilter from the elasticsearch project (maybe this one was not appropriate for the task, so this is not the really disadvantage for me)

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't `Set` use `hashCode()` internally? In which case you have `Long::hashCode(String::hashCode(URL))` in the `Set<Long>` case, which shouldn't really be an improvement, but is?

Comment: Also, -1 for the Justin Bieber link.

Comment: @aib I don't understand what you want to say what do you mean with the double colons? Also if you clicked the URLs it is your own fault. this is what people are posting at twitter. It was just one of the failing examples. not to promote anyone

Comment: Okay, *that* -1 was a joke :). By colons, I mean the implementation, the built-in hashing function for built-in types, e.g. `new Long(42).hashCode()`. If you already have hashCodes in the Set, it should be using hashCodes of those hashCodes internally, which shouldn't be that much better than a simple Set<String>. Which is why I'm wondering if it's an improvement. Though I'm intrigued now and will be doing my own tests...

Comment: @aib I see :) But no, there is at no place a set.hashCode called ... also no Long.hashCode My method just did a different hashCode implementation for the String (it is a static method as you cannot use a mixin or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use an [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). The collision rate should be much smaller.

Comment: Thanks, this also improved it a lot. Though I'll have to do speed testing too ;)

Comment: Seems to be 20% slower when using the normal Java way of `algo = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` and `for (byte b : algo.digest(str.getBytes())) { ret += ret * 31 + b; }`

Comment: but it is cool that it seems to work even if I only combine the first 6 bytes returned by the digest method (which returns 16 bytes)

Comment: +1. MD5 is the answer to all hashing problems, and sometimes it's even the right one.

Comment: @aib you say +1 but you don't do it ... strange or even sarcastic answers here?

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that works all the time, not just most of the time, short hashes aren't going to cut it. At any length shorter than about 128 bits, as you've observed, even an ideal hash will have a significant collision rate.g. What you have is a scaling problem, and all you're done by using hash codes is reduce the constant factor- it's still O(n).

It sounds like your strings have a lot of prefixes in common, though - have you considered using a trie to store them?

Comment: a Trie sounds like the perfect approach! +1

Comment: Thanks. I think a lot urls start with the same thing at the beginning (e.g. the shortened URLs), but I'm not sure if it will be a large improvement. I'll check.

Comment: Is there a way to use bigger hashes with native containers? (e.g. byte[], which MessageDigest seems to return)

Comment: @aib No - hashcodes are designed for different purposes than secure digest functions. If you are using a secure digest, though, presumably you have no need to store the original string. 16 bytes is probably not much shorter than the average URL, though!

Comment: Secure digest? I thought we were talking about MD5 :). Actually I was just wondering how dynamic (or flexible) standard Java stuff is, I'm still kinda new to it. It looks like one needs to roll their own hash table implementation for >int hashes.

Comment: MD5 is a secure digest function - just not a very secure one any longer. I really don't think rolling your own hashtable is the solution here - the problem isn't insufficiently long hashcodes, it's too little memory for your keys.